# Ansible Issue - [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, ansible, export

I've been holding off posting here because I feel like this issue could be too vague. I will try my best to explain. I have been through all of the existing questions but they don't seem relevant to what I am doing.

Basically, I have inherited 3 Ec2 Instances that are Dev / Staging / Live web applications in my new role. I use Ansible playbooks to migrate the Database between all environments. We recently had a new website that was deployed onto all three existing instances.

The Dev box recently died so I blew it away and launched a new one, the website looks fine, however exporting and importing the Database no longer works (on the new instance)

Below is the Ansible output:

```
TASK: [Export database to migrate] ********************************************
failed: [172.**.**.***] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "wp db export dbv2.sql --tables=t*******0_links,t*******0_options,t*******0_postmeta,t*******0_posts,taxlt4ws0_rg_form,taxlt4ws0_rg_form_meta,taxlt4ws0_rg_form_view,t*******0_term_relationships,t*******0_term_taxonomy,t*******0_termmeta,t*******0_terms,t*******0_usermeta,t*******0_users", "delta": "0:00:00.001594", "end": "2017-09-01 10:21:25.225355", "rc": 127, "start": "2017-09-01 10:21:25.223761", "warnings": []}
stderr: /bin/sh: 1: wp: not found

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

Things I've checked:

- Chmod on the folders it import/exports in/from.
- IAM Role is set
- Used Shell instead of Command in the Playbook
- Configs for each environment

I'm really stumped my Ansible knowledge is quite limited as I only picked it up a couple months ago and hadn't run into any issues (even with a new Website) until the Dev box had to be replaced.

Comment: Please list your play (the command that is running this). Additionally, show the output from both the `shell` and `command` versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ansible is referring to wpcli. It is not able to find its executable.

If this is the case,you need to install it with another task before that one.

Comment: This is correct, the installation of wp-cli was commented out of the setup task for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what this is complaining about is that whatever script you are using in module Export DB is not able to find a `wp` script or executable.

> stderr: /bin/sh: 1: wp: not found

Would recommend checking `which wp` or maybe do a find to see if it is on the staging or live instances to see what it is and install/copy it over to the Dev instances.

You can test this hypothesis by using a small test script:

```
#!/bin/sh
wp
```

create this script say test.sh, give it executable permissions and run it on all the env's to see where it fails.

Comment: Your answer was not exact but it led me to discover the problem. the wp-cli was not installing on the machine! Thanks for directing me.